# Логгирование в журнал событий ОС с помощью NLog

Tags: c#, логирование, nlog

Добрый день, только недавно начал использовать Nlog, довольно быстро в нем разобрался, но не смог понять как писать логи в журнал событий WIndows (7).

Нужно ли что-то дописывать в конфиг файл?

Как писать логи в ОС с помощью System.Diagnostic я знаю, но хотелось бы использовать для этого NLog. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам [сюда](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target) (пример оттуда):

```
<targets>
 <target xsi:type="EventLog"
      name="String"
      layout="Layout"
      machineName="String"
      source="Layout" 
      category="Layout"
      eventId="Layout"
      log="String"
      maxMessageLength="Integer" />
<!-- note: source is a string in NLog before 4.0 -->

</targets>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!